# Updating k9s on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes

I need to install k9s on ubuntu. I am using snap to do that, running the command
snap install k9s. However the version thats getting installed is 0.5.1. The latest version is 0.27.4. Can someone help me with how to update to latest version? Somewhere I read to just get the binaries for it, however not sure where to drop these binaries. Please help

Answer (score 0):

[k9s 0.27.4 download link from sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/k9s.mirror/files/v0.27.4/k9s_Linux_s390x.tar.gz/download)

You may need to build from source, not sure, but I did notice for linux install it only gave an option for brew and pacman but saw nothing using apt.
You can read more on that [here](https://k9scli.io/topics/install/#Building%20from%20Source)

To install using snap from terminal type sudo snap install k9s --channel=stable

[image]

Comment: I tried installing pacman with sudo apt , thinking then I can use pacman to install k9s but that installs the pacman game :)

Comment: You could install pacman(lot of blood sweat and tears) but that I'm afraid comes at a cost. Install other package mangers from other distro's can break your system. It's not impossible but comes at great cost leaving your system unstable. If you would like to read more on this you can check it out at https://lifehacker.com/pacapt-brings-arch-linuxs-amazing-pacman-package-manage-5880003

Comment: that not encouraging ... sounds like I should leave pacman alone...esp with the little ubuntu knowledge i have.

Comment: I would agree ;) You may want to look into building k9s from source.

Comment: After looking at the output of snap info k9s, I see the version you have installed is 0.5.1 which is the edge version. the stable version is 0.27.4, to install stable version(0.27.4)  from terminal type sudo snap install k9s --channel=stable. you may need to remove the current version of k9s first.